# How do I access environment variables in Strapi v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, environment-variables, strapi

- **Strapi Version**: 4.3.0
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 20.04
- **Database**: SQLite
- **Node Version**: 16.16
- **NPM Version**: 8.11.0
- **Yarn Version**: 1.22.19

I have created [Preview button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCW3S.png) for an article collection type. I'm using the Strapi blog template. I managed to make the Preview button appear in the **Content Manager**. I hard coded the link to be opened when you click the Preview button and it works. Now, I want the plugin to use a link with *environment variables* instead of a hard coded link. I don't know how I can access the environment variables in the source code for the plugin.

**My objective:**

I want to replace

```js
href={`http://localhost:3000?secret=abc&slug=${initialData.slug}`}
```

with

```js
href={${CLIENT_FRONTEND_URL}?secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&slug=${initialData.slug}`}
```

in *./src/plugins/previewbtn/admin/src/components/PreviewLink/index.js*

where `CLIENT_FRONTEND_URL` and `CLIENT_SECRET` are environment variables declared like so in **.env**:

```bash
CLIENT_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
CLIENT_PREVIEW_SECRET=abc
```

Here's a rundown of the code I used:

First, I created a strapi app using the blog template, then created a plugin.

```
// Create strapi app named backend with a blog template
 $  yarn create strapi-app backend  --quickstart --template @strapi/template-blog@1.0.0 blog && cd backend

// Create plugin
$ yarn strapi generate
```

Next, I created a PreviewLink file to provide a link for the Preview button

```js
// ./src/plugins/previewbtn/admin/src/components/PreviewLink/index.js
import React from 'react';
import { useCMEditViewDataManager } from '@strapi/helper-plugin';
import Eye from '@strapi/icons/Eye';
import { LinkButton } from '@strapi/design-system/LinkButton';

const PreviewLink = () => {
  const {initialData} = useCMEditViewDataManager();
  if (!initialData.slug) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <LinkButton
      size="S"
      startIcon={<Eye/>}
      style={{width: '100%'}}
      href={`http://localhost:3000?secret=abc&slug=${initialData.slug}`}
      variant="secondary"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
      title="page preview"
    >Preview
    </LinkButton>
  );
};

export default PreviewLink;
```

Then I edited this pregenerated file in the `bootstrap(app) { ... }` section only

```js
// ./src/plugins/previewbtn/admin/src/index.js
import { prefixPluginTranslations } from '@strapi/helper-plugin';
import pluginPkg from '../../package.json';
import pluginId from './pluginId';
import Initializer from './components/Initializer';
import PreviewLink from './components/PreviewLink';
import PluginIcon from './components/PluginIcon';

const name = pluginPkg.strapi.name;
export default {
  register(app) {
    app.addMenuLink({
      to: `/plugins/${pluginId}`,
      icon: PluginIcon,
      intlLabel: {
        id: `${pluginId}.plugin.name`,
        defaultMessage: name,
      },
      Component: async () => {
        const component = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ './pages/App');
        return component;
      },

      permissions: [
        // Uncomment to set the permissions of the plugin here
        // {
        //   action: '', // the action name should be plugin::plugin-name.actionType
        //   subject: null,
        // },
      ],
    });

    app.registerPlugin({
      id: pluginId,
      initializer: Initializer,
      isReady: false,
      name,
    });
  },

  bootstrap(app) {
    app.injectContentManagerComponent('editView', 'right-links', {
      name: 'preview-link',
      Component: PreviewLink
    });
  },

  async registerTrads({ locales }) {
    const importedTrads = await Promise.all(
      locales.map(locale => {
        return import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "translation-[request]" */ `./translations/${locale}.json`
        )

          .then(({ default: data }) => {
            return {
              data: prefixPluginTranslations(data, pluginId),
              locale,
            };
          })

          .catch(() => {
            return {
              data: {},
              locale,
            };
          });
      })
    );
    return Promise.resolve(importedTrads);
  },
};
```

And lastly this created this file to enable the plugin [Reference](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins-development.html#create-a-plugin)

```js
// ./config/plugins.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    'preview-btn': {
      enabled: true,
      resolve: './src/plugins/previewbtn' // path to plugin folder
    },
    // ...
  }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a **custom webpack configuration** to enable Strapi's admin frontend to access the environment variables as global variables.

I renamed *./src/admin/webpack.example.config.js* to *./src/admin/webpack.config.js*. Refer to the [v4 code migration: Updating the webpack configuration](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/update-migration-guides/migration-guides/v4/code/frontend/webpack.html) from the Official Strapi v4 Documentation.

I then inserted the following code, with help from Official webpack docs: [DefinePlugin | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) :

```js
// ./src/admin/webpack.config.js
'use strict';

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
module.exports = (config, webpack) => {
  // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
  // Perform customizations to webpack config
  // Important: return the modified config
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CLIENT_FRONTEND_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.CLIENT_FRONTEND_URL),
      CLIENT_PREVIEW_SECRET: JSON.stringify(process.env.CLIENT_PREVIEW_SECRET),
    })
  )

  return config;
};
```

I rebuilt my app afterwards and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to change the webpack config just find .env file in the root directory
add

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = your key here
```

then just import by
 `accessKeyId: env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')`